# How to call second class when button pressed?

Tags: java, swing

Iam making a simple program where the user enters name and description. If the user presses OK, the program will write the result to the file. Basically, i have 3 classes. I want to call my class2 from class1 and implement the method. I know how to do it in only one class but i would like to know this way too. Thanks in advance.

The problem is that the inputs cannot be added to the file. Maybe iam not calling the file name properly:

```
   if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

class2 ad = new class2(this);
   }
```

Below are my 3 classes:

Main

```
public class mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class1 a = new class1();
    }
}
```

Class1

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

public class class1{

final JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
final JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public  class1() {

        panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Description:"));
        panel.add(field2);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,"Enter Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            class2 ad = new class2 ();
        }
    }
}
```

Class2

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class class2 {

    class1 a;

    public class2(class1 a) {

        this.a = a;

        a = new class1();

        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {

            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("file.txt", true));

            String add1 = a.field1.getText();
            String add2 = a.field2.getText();

            writer.write(add1);
            writer.write("\t");
            writer.write(add2);
            writer.write("\t");

        } catch ( IOException e) {

        } finally {
            try {
            if ( writer != null)
                writer.close( );
            } catch ( IOException e) {
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question.

Comment: `"The problem"` - what's the problem with it? Some error message?

Comment: Yes. the inputs cannot be added to the file.

Comment: stacktrace you catch blocks

Comment: Bingo what is stacktrace?

Comment: OK. I put it under catch(IOEException). But this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @DamBokser In the `catch` block - `catch ( IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: OK. I put it under catch(IOEException). But this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @DamBokser It's not supposed to solve the issue, it's just supposed to print something out if something goes wrong.

Comment: As an aside, also use conventional class names; +1 for including an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `a = new class1()` in `class2` creates a different instance than the one created in `mainclass`. Instead, pass a reference to `class1` to your `class2` constructor.

```
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    class2 ad = new class2(this);
}
...
public class2(class1 a) {
    //a = new class1();
    this.a = a;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i did it, but nothing added to the file.

Comment: It worked for me when I just tried it again. In fact, I saw the extra tab characters from a previous (failed) run. You might want to edit your question to show your current approach.

Comment: You forgot to comment out `a = new class1()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is **a** problem.

The constructor of `class1` creates an instance of `class2` here:

```
class2 ad = new class2();
```

Which calls the constructor of `class2`.

Which creates an instance of `class1` here:

```
a = new class1();
```

Which calls the constructor of `class1`.

Which prompts you again.

So you only get to the rest of the constructor of `class2` after the second prompt (if you cancel).

Comment: So could you please tell me the correct way of calling the second class?

Comment: @DamBokser Why is it even in a class at all, why not just make it a method in `class1`?

Comment: because i know how to do it inside the same class. I would like to learn to call methods of other classes.